# Type interference in the call join

Tags: c#, linq

I have built a short and sweet join query to try and get a feel on how to create a join. I managed to do it in SQL. But I'm not sure how to do it in LINQ.

LINQ:

```
public IQueryable<DepartmentBreakdownReport> GetDepartmentBreakdown
    (int SupplierID, int ReviewPeriodID)
{
    return (from detail in camOnlineDb.Details
            join suppDepp in camOnlineDb.SuppDepts
                on new { detail.ClientID, detail.CategoryID }
            equals new { suppDepp.ClientID, suppDepp.CategoryID }
            select detail.ClientID + "" + detail.CategoryID);
}
```

Edit: Ignore the parameters which are brought in, I will cater to those once I have my join working.

Comment: Can you paste your sql query?

Comment: In what way is this query not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an `IQueryable<string>` rather than what I assume you want is `IQueryable<DepartmentBreakdownReport>`. To return that type, you need to project in the `select` by specifying the type, something like this:

```
return (from detail in camOnlineDb.Details
        join suppDepp in camOnlineDb.SuppDepts
            on new { detail.ClientID, detail.CategoryID }
        equals new { suppDepp.ClientID, suppDepp.CategoryID }
        select new DepartmentBreakdownReport
        {
            Property1 = detail.Property1,
            //your properties here
        });
```

Comment: I'm going to choose your answer because ultimately you were right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Category ID was nullable in Detail but not in suppDepp.

To fix it I changed it from a non-nullable type